# How to access data using a SQL query that references multiple tables?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a few tables and inserted values into them using SQL plus:

```
INSERT INTO Location(name, addr, phone) 
VALUES ('Texas Branch', '4832 Deercove Drive, Dallas, TX 75208', '214-948-7102');

INSERT INTO Librarian(eid, ID, pay, Loc_name) 
VALUES (2591051, 88564, 30000.00, 'Texas Branch');

INSERT INTO Stored_In(media_id, name) 
VALUES (8733, 'Texas Branch');
```

Suppose I write a SQL query like `select location = "texas branch"`, then the output should contain the librarian for the Texas branch and `media_id`, the name `stored_in`  - in simple words, I should get all the information related to Texas branch)

Can anyone please help write the SQL query?

Comment: Lookup on `Joins`. Also you can add a Identity column to `Location` table and refer it in `Librarian` and `Stored_In` table

Answer (score 1):

Something along the lines of:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    Location
    INNER JOIN 
    Librarian ON Location.name = Librarian.Loc_name
    INNER JOIN 
    Stored_In ON Stored_In.name = Location.name
)
WHERE(
    Location.name='Texas Branch'
)
```

Because of the `SELECT *` you will get a bunch of duplicate fields and you should replace this with the proper select.

As others have said, Google `JOIN`s and understand them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use joins then the SQL is straightforward.  If that is unclear then maybe you need to do some homework.

Comment: My concern, Drew, is that nadh is obviously trying to write an application that uses data from a database without - apparently - knowledge of joins.  This is a situation fraught with problems, among which is the lack of knowledge of relational database design and table relations.  In that light, writing his SQL for him/her is simply putting off a learning experience that needs to come before the writing of an application.  YMMV.